# PostgreSQL : ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE with primary key error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to set up a constraint in my query : I got one column that contain a token and I want to change it if necessary. So I set up my query like this :

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
values ('john','someUUID','token')
ON CONFLICT (token)
    DO UPDATE
        SET token = EXCLUDED.token
```

I thought that works but pgSQL give me the following error :

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_uuid_unique"
DETAIL:  Key (uuid)=(someUUID) already exists.
SQL state: 23505
```

It seems that pgSQL want to duplicate the row...
How can I just edit my column ?

PS :
My table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.mytable (
    username character varying(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    uuid character varying(64) NOT NULL,
    token character varying(41)
);

ALTER TABLE ONLY mytable
    ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_token_unique UNIQUE (token);


ALTER TABLE ONLY mytable
    ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_username_unique UNIQUE (username);

ALTER TABLE ONLY mytable
    ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_uuid_unique UNIQUE (uuid);
```

******EDIT******_
To be more precise, I want to do this query on a empty table:

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
values ('john','someUUID','token')
ON CONFLICT (token)
    DO UPDATE
        SET token = EXCLUDED.token
```

And later do this query :

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
values ('john','someUUID','token2')
ON CONFLICT (token)
    DO UPDATE
        SET token = EXCLUDED.token
```

And the only column that is modified is token (from 'token' to 'token2')
Hope that is more clear

Comment: Well, you are checking for conflicts on `token`, but the error message states that the conflict is on the `uuid` column. If you want to modify an existing row, then why don't you just use `UPDATE`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: hmm, but it will cause that error if the value for the column `uuid` already exists in the table. Whether or not that column is modified, seems irrelevant here

Comment: `where conflict_target can be one of:

    ( { index_column_name | ( index_expression ) }`

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe but the _insert_ will trigger a unique constraint violation for the constraint `mytable_uuid_unique` because `someUUID` already exists and thus the conflict on `token` won't matter. One unique constraint on each column doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ahh, the light is dawning on me. The `INSERT` already causes the constraint violation. Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reproduce the error like this:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (username, uuid, token)
   VALUES ('john', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 'token')
   ON CONFLICT (token)
      DO UPDATE SET token = EXCLUDED.token;

INSERT 0 1

INSERT INTO mytable (username, uuid, token)
   VALUES ('john2', '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', 'token2')
   ON CONFLICT (token)
      DO UPDATE SET token = EXCLUDED.token;

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_uuid_unique"
DETAIL:  Key (uuid)=(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) already exists.
```

The second insert does not have a conflict on `token`, so the `ON CONFLICT` clause does not apply. So the `INSERT` proceeds and gives you a constraint violation because of the duplicate entry for `uuid`.

That should be just what you want, judging from your constraint definitions.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and works fine, pg14.2

```
u: postgres db: testpart # CREATE TABLE public.mytable (
#     username character varying(40) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
#     uuid character varying(64) NOT NULL,
#     token character varying(41)
# );
CREATE TABLE
Time: 60.377 ms
u: postgres db: testpart # 
u: postgres db: testpart # ALTER TABLE ONLY mytable
#     ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_token_unique UNIQUE (token);
ALTER TABLE
Time: 8.605 ms
u: postgres db: testpart # 
u: postgres db: testpart # 
u: postgres db: testpart # ALTER TABLE ONLY mytable
#     ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_username_unique UNIQUE (username);
ALTER TABLE
Time: 4.810 ms
u: postgres db: testpart # 
u: postgres db: testpart # ALTER TABLE ONLY mytable
#     ADD CONSTRAINT mytable_uuid_unique UNIQUE (uuid);
ALTER TABLE
Time: 5.074 ms
u: postgres db: testpart # 
u: postgres db: testpart # INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
# values ('john','someUUID','token')
# ON CONFLICT (token)
#     DO UPDATE
#         SET token = EXCLUDED.token;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 11.091 ms
u: postgres db: testpart # INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
values ('john','someUUID','token')
ON CONFLICT (token)
    DO UPDATE
        SET token = EXCLUDED.token;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 6.142 ms
u: postgres db: testpart # INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
values ('john','someUUID','token')
ON CONFLICT (token)
    DO UPDATE
        SET token = EXCLUDED.token;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 5.112 ms
u: postgres db: testpart # select * from mytable;
 username |   uuid   | token 
----------+----------+-------
 john     | someUUID | token
(1 row)

Time: 0.450 ms
```

Comment: I add some information in my question but I want to make multiple query with the same username and uuid, only my token change like :
INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
        values ('john','someUUID','token')
   and    
INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
       values ('john','someUUID','token2')

Answer (score 0):

I got no error in my [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=67c0b2bab105e0714078dc2685eece6d) until I change 'token' to 'token2' and username 'John' to 'John1' in the 2nd insert statement.

```
 -- first row insert
    INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
    values ('john','someUUID','token')
    ON CONFLICT (token)
        DO UPDATE
            SET token = EXCLUDED.token;
    -- here is the error 
    INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
    values ('john1','someUUID','token2')
    ON CONFLICT (token)
        DO UPDATE
            SET token = EXCLUDED.token;
    
    ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "mytable_uuid_unique"
    DETAIL:  Key (uuid)=(someUUID) already exists.
```

In this case, the error is here because you are trying to insert the second row with a unique key already existing in the table by uuid ('someUUID').

Feel free to change my code or variable values to show us the error you are getting.

I would also like to clarify what is the reason to creating these unique indexes (separately for each column)? Maybe it makes sense to change them to a composite index?

Comment: I update my question, but yes this is my problem. I just want to change the token column value without creating another row

Answer (score 0):

You should use `ON CONFLICT (username)` or `ON CONFLICT (uuid)` ,because in scenario when during inserting new record constraints on this fields are violated, you want to update token instead of inserting a new record.

```sql
INSERT INTO mytable (username,uuid,token)
values ('john','someUUID','token2')
ON CONFLICT (username)
    DO UPDATE
        SET token = EXCLUDED.token
```

If fields `username` and `uuid` are set only during insert, than you can use `uuid` interchangeably with `username`.
But if one of this fields (`uuid,username`) can be changed after inserting then there  are some more complicated scenarios you must take care of.